# PHP Array of a stdClass, How to get data?

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

I would like to print the value of [name].  I am just becoming familiar with [standard defined classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php) and how they are called.

Based on this example and logic

```
$arrayobj = new ArrayObject(array('first','second','third'));
print_r($arrayobj);
//outputs: ArrayObject Object ( [0] => first [1] => second [2] => third )
```

With that.  I'm trying to extract the value of name (Pebbles) out of here.

```
print_r($terms);
/* outputs
Array ( [3] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 3 [name] => Pebbles ) )
*/
```

So I tried

```
echo $terms[0]->name;
```

Got peanuts. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only array key listed is `[3]` (`Array ( [3] => stdClass...`), so use

```
echo $terms[3]->name;
```

Even though it is a numerically indexed array, that doesn't mean it starts with an index of 0 or even has sequential keys.

Get them all with a loop:

```
foreach ($terms as $t) {
   echo $t->name;
}
```

Comment: you beat me to it with 5sec ... nice one

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I am wrong, but you can typecast them.

```
$terms = (array) $terms;
```

Will make it a normal array accessible through:

```
$terms[3]['name']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following :

```
echo $terms[3]->name ;
```

Answer (score 0):

To display the value of the objects fiel name, you can use this command:

```
    echo $this[3]->name;
```